# How can I programmatically access work items on Team Foundation Service?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I'm developing a WPF application that would allow me to access specific work items of a Team Foundation **Server** and this is relatively simple by following the tutorial Microsoft provides [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb286958.aspx).

But I wonder if it would be possible to do the same thing for Team Foundation **Service**. I thought that the concept is similar but I'm struggling with this.

I managed to connect my Team Foundation Service to Visual Studio 2012 so I'm certain that I can access these work items. I was wondering if this can be done programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done programmatically. The concept is similar but the authentication is different. Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx) for information regarding alternate credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do, first you just identify what type of connection server provides. WCF or socket etc.. And create client you the and connect to the server and get the data